# UPN vs EMAIL for Azure AD Connect

Tags: microsoft-office-365, entra-id

In our AD our emails don't match our UPN, so when we sync with Azure AD using UPN any accounts that have been pre-created don't match. We get two accounts for the od user.

lets assume upn is `user@xyz.co.uk` email is `user.name@xyz.co.uk`

If we plan to DELETE the miss matched accounts and just leave the UPNs will this create a problem for tools such as Skype for business (other than having to login with the UPN and it being a different USER)? Will external users be able to find our Skype users if they search by email?

I understand that deleting the duplicated accounts may also create problems for things like favourites in the `Skype for business` client.

We are not using exchange online (yet)

Or, if we CHANGE the UPNs to match the email, will this change just flow through to AzureAD? eg if we change UPN from `user@xyz.co.uk` to `user.name@xyz.co.uk` will the user be able to start using `user.name@xyz.co.uk` or will it get in a muddle.

I understand that any internal apps that use UPN may need to be looked at.

Or, should we just sync using the email address as the unique key and just leave the UPN as is. I guess we will need to turn off syncing and re-install the tools.

Answer (score 1):

> if we CHANGE the UPNs to match the email, will this change just flow
>   through to AzureAD?

If we change the UPNs to match the email from local, Azure AD connect will **update** Azure AD users' information.

> should we just sync using the email address as the unique key and just
>   leave the UPN as is.

we can change the UPN, then sync them, Azure AD users, information will be update.

Also we can delete Azure AD user(duplicated), then use AAD connect to sync them again.

---

**Update:**

> I guess we will need to turn off syncing and re-install the tools.

You are right, it is a good way to achieve it.

We should stop sync task, uninstall AAD connect, and use PowerShell `Remove-AzureADuser` to delete users from Azure AD, then reinstall Azure AD connect and use `mail` to sync users to Azure AD.

Comment: 3rd option, can we turn off sync, uninstall, reinstall and sync with the mail attribute. Or can this be done without reinstalling maybe via PowerShell? Thanks

Comment: @SteveDrake We can't sync them with PowerShell, we should change AAD connect rules to sync them. As a workaround, we can uninstall AAD connect and use Powershell to delete users in Azure AD, then install AAD connect to sync them with `mail` attribute.

Comment: @SteveDrake I have update my answer, please check it, thanks:)